# Middleware using cookie nuxt

Tags: vue.js, routes, middleware, nuxt.js

I just setup middleware by checking cookie in nuxt but it's give me blank error, nothing error in console

[image]

this is my middleware `authenticate.js`

```
export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  const Cookie = process.client ? require('js-cookie') : undefined
  // If the user is not authenticated
  let token = Cookie.get('token')
  const userIsLoggedIn = token != null //cookie ada
  const userNeedLogin = token == null //cookie gak ada
  if (userNeedLogin) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
  if (userIsLoggedIn) {
    return redirect('/dashboard')
  }
}
```

and this is my nuxt.config.js

```
router: { 
    middleware: 'authenticate'
  }
```

it should redirect to page login when cookies is null but if cookie exist it redirect goes to dashboard, do i miss something ?

Comment: Your image suggests nuxt is looking for 'authenticated' rather than 'authenticate'. Also I use 'cookie' rather than 'js-cookie' for getting my cookies (js-cookie to set them) so maybe you could try that. And I call my get_cookies (as I call it) function in nuxtServerInit then just use middleware for validating. Can post code in an answer if you think it will help.

Comment: where came from authenticated, you can see i call the same name or should i renamed it ? i just renamed it in nuxt.config.js and name file it  and came new error Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: I know, just what the image in your question shows. I would have thought the file name and in nuxt.config.js are the only places it's referenced and they both seem fine. Might be a worth trying re-naming, just 'auth' perhaps.

Comment: @Andrew1325 by the way i use https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-external-jwt/, going to use cookie ans see whats an error